# Can I shorten the neutral pigtail of a GFCI breaker?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, gfci, neutral

I want to clean up clutter in my 200 amp GE Electrical panel prior to installing a 50 amp transfer switch.  Can I uncoil AND shorten the neutral pigtail of the GFCI breakers?

Comment: What make and model of transfer switch are you trying to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, leave enough of the neutral pig tails in case you need to move the breakers later, but there is nothing wrong with straighten them out and cutting shorter.

Answer (score 3):

### It's not going to work

Since your panel has enough GFCI/AFCI breakers to worry about pigtail clutter, it only follows that you're hoping to put one of those GFCI circuits on the transfer switch.

That's not going to work.  Those old 6/8/10 circuit transfer switches were designed with a very 1960s mentality for handling neutral (or to be more precise, *not* handling it). The result is they Simply Do Not Work with GFCI and AFCI breakers. They have a lot of other design issues, like they can create a hazard with multi-wire branch circuits.

### Instead, go with a *sliding-plate interlock*

This is a backfeed breaker that lets the generator feed your whole panel.  It won't power every load, so you'll have to turn some off.

Each circuit's breaker remains its same breaker. GFCI and AFCI protection is preserved (which is a Code requirement, yes? It's a Code requirement in generator mode too.)

Now you may have heard that you shouldn't backfeed the panel because that could light up the grid and shock linemen. True; that's what the *sliding plate interlock* does for you.  It assures you must turn the utility main breaker off before turning the generator backfeed breaker on.

Again since you have a number of GFCI breakers I'm guessing you have a newer panel, and that means you can get approved interlocks *from the manufacturer of the panel*. Prices range from $25 to $80. Add a $15 240V breaker, the same wiring, and an inlet on the outside of your house.

You never want the inlet indoors. That necessitates generator cords coming through doors, which means doors cracked open, and that has been tied to countless deaths from carbon monoxide poisoning.